# Python ping scanner execution optimisation

Tags: python, networking, optimization, ping

I am trying to improve the execution time on the following network scanner script because its too slow. Any suggestions?

```
import subprocess
import os

with open(os.devnull, "wb") as limbo:
    for n in xrange(1, 10):
        ip = "192.168.0.{0}".format(n)
        result = subprocess.Popen(["ping", "-c", "1", "-n", "-W", "2", ip],
                                  stdout=limbo, stderr=limbo).wait()
        if result:
            print
            ip, "inactive"
        else:
            print
            ip, "active"
```